# Graphing calculator for third year undergrad applied modules

Tags: calculator

Can someone recommend me a good and affordable calculator please. I am going to sit exams like partial differential equations (method of characteristics related stuff), nonlinear dynamical systems and fluid dynamics.

I need one that can sketch really complicated functions like $y=sec{h} ^2 (x) \tanh^2 (x)$.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I've taken a PDEs class and a fluids class, and my TI-84 (Silver Plus, I believe) from high school was more than sufficient. Almost all of the undergraduates at my university used this model during exams, and on problem sets it was a mix of the TI-84 and software like MATLAB/Maple.

Comment: @SSS Thanks, but its quite expensive! £50 for a calculator...

Comment: Fair - I didn't think much of it because I've gotten 7.5 years of use out of it (so far). Depending on your major and your prospects for graduate school, you also might get enough use out of it to justify the price. I'm a fan of TI products, so you might want to check out the TI-83 and see if it's more within your budget (you don't really lose much functionality).